# restrict a character to type in a text box

Tags: html

how we can restrict a character to type in a text box.

Comment: Can you be more clear. You mean you want to restrict users from entering some particular characters in a text box is it?

Answer (score 23):

You can do this via javascript (so if javascript is off, you won't be able to restrict it)

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />
```

This will restrict it to only a-z characters. Checkout [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to see what you can do

Comment: Remember that this code only executes on the client side. The server script must be prepared to handle **any** input and reject invalid characters.

Comment: This needs a global flag on the regex. This is because one can hold a key down and have it commit many key down events (and add many numbers) before release, at which point only 1 key up event goes...meaning only one of the possibly many non-desired characters would get deleted since without a global flag it only replaces 1 per call.

Answer (score 11):

Although still possible, with HTML5 there's no real need to use a JavaScript-based solution for this requirement.

`<input type="text" name="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">` will restrict the allowed characters according that RegExp pattern (in this case: valid-looking email addresses).

The `title` attribute will be used as a warning / notification when the user tries to submit the data not matching the requirement.

```
<form action="/add_country.php">
  Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

See the [documentation on HTML input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for more information. Not all browsers support it equally well (like Safari) though.

Comment: This doesn't restrict the characters you can type, it validates the contents after submission.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the text box then you have to handle the `onkeypress` event

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='keypresshandler(event)' />
```

You can use the following function to restrict the users

```
    function keypresshandler(event)
    {
         var charCode = event.keyCode;
         //Non-numeric character range
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach, and found you needed to use onkeypress = 'return keypresshandler(event)' for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Ben Rowe's answer is indeed the way to approach it. However, the character will appear in the textbox before it is being removed. You can prevent that by using `oninput` instead of `onkeyup`:

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   function isNumberKey1(evt)
{
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if ( char!=8(charCode < 65 || charCode > 106))
         return false;

         return true;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your code. Why your solution is better then other posted solutions?