# How to make "Enter" key in a textarea submit a form

Tags: html, forms

I have a chat that uses textarea instead of text for obvious reasons. This is why each time members hit ENTER they get a new line instead of sending the message. 
I would like to change this, so every time they hit ENTER =the message to be submitted and then the cursor to return on textarea for their next message typing.
I've tried different codes found on this site, most didnt work and those who seemed to do something  were just refreshing the page and i got a blank page.

My code:

```
<form name="message" action="">
    <textarea name="usermsg" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="usermsg" rows="4" cols="30" style="width: 450px; margin-left: 25px;">
    </textarea>
    <br/>

    <p style="margin-left: 420px;"><input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about? HTML?

Comment: Php is the programming language.

Comment: Maybe because if you type too long text in `<input type="text">`, text won't wrap like in textarea.

Comment: programming language should be irrelevant here since this is a client side request.

Comment: Um..I'll go read about textbox and see what this is about. Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle with an example on how to do it with jQuery and the `keypress`function and `which` property: http://jsfiddle.net/GcdUE/

Not sure exactly what you are asking for more than this, so please specify your question further if possible.

```
$(function() {
    $("#usermsg").keypress(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            //submit form via ajax, this is not JS but server side scripting so not showing here
            $("#chatbox").append($(this).val() + "<br/>");
            $(this).val("");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Anders, this works but the message only stays for a second and then dissapears from chat.

Comment: Ok, edited something to fit with my chat and your code works perfectly now, thank you all, you've been most kind!

Comment: Is good, but is better when change [ if (e.which == 13) { ] to [ if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {  ] ////// In this way we can type SHIFT+ENTER to new line.

Comment: A big issue with the answer is different (non-romanic) language input such as Chinese or Japanese. There you need to click enter to finalize your input and then enter

Answer (score 57):

Try this (note that pressing **Enter** submits, and **Shift+Enter** adds a new line).

```
$("#textareaId").keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote this example. But the reason for return false is to prevent the event propagation (just like it does: e.preventDefault ()). Maybe it's unnecessary, but I do not remember. So testing,

Comment: Pressing Enter seems to send the form (at least the form is closed) but contents of the textarea are not saved.

Comment: @SergioCabral using e.preventDefault (); is helpful because after pressing Enter, only JS starts without adding a new line to the textarea.

Answer (score 48):

Vanilla JavaScript solution

```js
function submitOnEnter(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        if (!event.repeat) {
            const newEvent = new Event("submit", {cancelable: true});
            event.target.form.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
        }

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the addition of a new line in the text field
    }
}

document.getElementById("usermsg").addEventListener("keydown", submitOnEnter);
```

---

If you would prefer to add a new line when Shift is held all you need to do is change line 2 to:

```js
if (event.which === 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
```

---

To clear the textarea just add this after the `dispatchEvent` line:

```js
event.target.value = "";
```

---

To use this with Internet Explorer 11 change line 4 and 5 to:

```js
var newEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
newEvent.initEvent("submit", false, true);
event.target.form.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

---

> But wait? Why not use `event.target.form.submit();`?

When you invoke the submit method of the form the event listeners will not be called.

---

```js
function submitOnEnter(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        if (!event.repeat) {
            const newEvent = new Event("submit", {cancelable: true});
            event.target.form.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
        }

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the addition of a new line in the text field
    }
}

document.getElementById("usermsg").addEventListener("keydown", submitOnEnter);

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <textarea id="usermsg"></textarea>
    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: please note, that `new Event()` will not work in IE11

Comment: @pttsky added a note about IE 11

Comment: Thumb up for vanilla. Who wants jQuery anyways?

Comment: The `keypress` event is deprecated. Use `keydown` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Comment: `event.target.form.requestSubmit();` is cleaner than `dispatchEvent`. All modern browsers support it, as of Safari 16.

Comment: "as of Safari 16" is the reason you should not use this yet. Safari 15 if still recent for such an important UX functionality.

Comment: To add to the comments regarding the browser compatibility discussion: This is fully stable in functionality now. For more info, check: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_event_event

Answer (score 5):

Well, supposing you were using jquery it would be a simple listener on your input field:

In your footer before </body>:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#usermsg').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
           // submit via ajax or
           $('form').submit();
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

In your html head add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

but if js or jquery is out of the question then perhaps update your question to specifically exclude it.

Comment: I tried it but doesnt seem to work or i simply don't know how to do it right. do i need to change something from code? ty

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, I forgot to add your id to the textarea.

Comment: Ok, now it had a response, seems like i inserted it correctly but i get a blank page like refresh.

Comment: Anders code seems to be the one for my chat it sends the message but for some reason the message only appears 1 second it chat and that puf vanishes. strange.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with your php code then. Cause if this works then your back end isn't doing its job.

Answer (score -1):

To capture Enter key in textarea in TailwindCSS:

```
              onkeypress={(e)=>{
                if(e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) {
                  INVOKE_YOUR_FUNCTION();
                }
              }}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function KP()
{    
var x = event.keyCode;
   if(x==13)
        {
            // alert (x);
            document.message.submit();
        }
}
```

php

```
echo '<textarea  name="usrMsg" id="usrMsg" OnKeyPress="KP();">'txt'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Please consider what you are doing.

Comment: While this does submit the form, it also puts a line-feed in the SELECT box in some browsers, which you don't want if the form stays put. To fix, have the function return "false" for Enter, and put "return KP();" in the caller. For similar examples, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059559/restrict-a-character-to-type-in-a-text-box

Answer (score -4):

Use `<input type=text>` instead of `<textarea>`. Then you have much better chances. In `textarea`, hitting Enter is supposed to mean a line break in text, not submission of text.

Comment: Yes, i know, it used to be text but it's a problem for a chat where longer posts are made (like in this comment box) , to have just one line. Thank you for taking the time to answer.