# Trigger callback on form submit

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem, What I'm doing is there is a `<form>` which has a `<textarea>`. What I want to achieve is when the user press the `Enter` key
on `textarea` then the form is submitted.

The default form is attached with an `eventListener` `submit` and execute a callback function.

But the problem is I want to execute that callback on `Enter` key.

I know I could achieve that same behavior by using JQuery `.submit(callback)` method.

But is there a way in Vanilla javascript re-trigger the same callback function.

```js
const submitForm = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('form is submitted!');
};

// Form Event
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm, false);

// Key Event
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Form submit
  }
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 380px;
  min-height: 210px;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
  <label>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: in the textarea **enter** key means a new line, you can override the default behavior and can make **shift + enter** a new line so that on **enter** form is submitted. refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934088/how-to-make-enter-key-in-a-textarea-submit-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form tag needs to have an `action`, or else the `form.submit()` won't do anything.

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <label>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea></label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This JS will call submit when pressing enter

```
let form = document.getElementById('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault()
        form.submit()
    }
});
```

But the real problem is that `form.submit()` will not raise the `onSubmit` event! So your `eventHandler` won't be called when you sumbit the form programmatically.

From MDN

> The submit event only fires when the user clicks a submit button ( or ) in a form. The event is not raised when calling the form.submit() method directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: `form.submit()` will perform default form behavior i.e. redirect to page. Do we prevent default behavior?

Comment: Since `form.submit()` does not fire an event, we cannot use `preventDefault()`. But the question is, why do you even use submit, if you don't want to submit the form? If you don't want to submit the form, you can just use a normal button instead of a submit button, and process the textarea however you want when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: I would suggest leaving out the form tag entirely, and just use javascript to process what is happening in the text field. If the enter key is pressed, you can call an AJAX function to send the data somewhere. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```js
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

if (event.keyCode === 13) {

  event.preventDefault();

  // do your thing here
  document.getElementById('form').submit();

  document.getElementById('testId').innerHTML = "it works!!!!"; // test

}


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
<form id="form" name="form" action="/your_page.aspx">
   <label><textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea></label>
</form>
  
<p id="testId"> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also know that. You're saying that I attach eventListener on keypress.

Comment: Yes. What is missing? I am not so sure what you are trying to achieve @VenNilson

Comment: Which technologies you are using on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to determine if the form is allowed to submit.

```
var allow_submit = false;
```

And modify the form's submit event handler so that `event.preventDefault()` is called if the `allow_submit` variable isn't `true`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  if (allow_submit !== true) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  // the form is allowed to submit, do stuff
});
```

Then listen for a `keyup` event (on the textarea) and if the enter key (keycode `13`) was pressed, set `allow_submit` to `true` and submit the form:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    allow_submit = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
  }
  // enter key wasn't pressed, do other suff
});
```

**NOTE:** you might have to make the `allow_submit` variable a global variable, you can do so by replacing `var` with `window.`, like this:

```
window.allow_submit = true;
```

**NOTE:** you should store the form and textarea elements in a variable, if you're going to use them a lot.

Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't work, because the submit event handler is not called when using `form.submit()`

Comment: It appears I've made a mistake, in the second block of code I wrote: `document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].submit();` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();`. Have you changed it? If not, I've edited my answer and you should try again.

Comment: Also, your example code doesn't contain a variable declaration for `form`, what is the value of that variable? Are you sure you're selecting the right element?

Comment: The real problem is that `form.submit()` does not fire a `submit event`. So the `eventListener` cannot catch this event and then prevent it.

Comment: Why not? Is it the Markup or JavaScript?

Comment: Sadly it's default browser behaviour, you can read it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: Could you use Ajax? If so, you could remove the textarea from the form and when enter is pressed you could create a GET/POST request to the form's action.

Comment: Yes, the best solution would be to call an AJAX function when enter is pressed in the textarea, and leave out the form tag, and form action entirely.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem, good luck with your project.