# Restricting integer in a textfiled

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I created sample spring MVC program to display the student name, id and age.  I want to restrict entering of numbers in the textfield and string in place for age.  Also I want to make the id field mandatory.  I am using JSP for the view.

I had searched a lot but cannot find a suitable solution
   I am expecting your help,
  Thanks in advance.
This is the jsp file

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
 </head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>

 <form:form method="POST" action="addstudent">

<table>
  <tr>
     <td><form:label path="name" id="tct" >Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="age" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label> </td>
    <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </td>

</tr>

</table> 

</form:form>
```

This were the search result i have found

[restrict a character to type in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059559/restrict-a-character-to-type-in-a-text-box#comment3132818_3059596)

[Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point)

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox

if this link works please help me to integrate it with my JSP file.I am beginner in javascript and HTML.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what solutions did you find? what did you try? take a look to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html

Comment: spring-mvc validation will work only after posting data to server. Are you sure you want this? Maybe validation need to be implemented on html/js side before posting?

Comment: I would alternatively suggest to take a look at HTML5 form validation features such as the `pattern` attribute, where you could restrict user inputs without one single line of JS.

Answer (score 0):

For non-numerical fields:
One possible solution is to use the keyup function to replace all number occurrences in the text field while you type (jQuery used).

```
$(".textfield").keyup(function(){
    var textfield= $(this).val();
    var newtext=textfield.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    $(this).val(newtext);

});
```

For numerical only fields:
You can use something similar as the above but replace the regexpression with:

```
 var newtext=textfield.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
```

For id:
Use form validation on form submission. First of give an id/name to your form.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var idField= $(#idField).val();
    if(idField.length > 0){ //form ok

    }else{ //form not ok. error message
      alert('error');
    }
});
```

I haven't actually tested the above code completely so any corrections would be appreciated.

Hope it helps