# How to prevent the use of some characters in an input field

Tags: html

In a form I use an input field to rename a filename. How can I prevent the use of / and . ??
All letters and numbers are ok.
I tried with pattern="" but don't know what to put there...

Comment: pattern is not prevent them, it will throw an error when you try to submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restrict a character to type in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059559/restrict-a-character-to-type-in-a-text-box)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) — Don't fight it, just *encode* whatever input you receive correctly. In the case of file paths, you may want to *replace* special characters with underscores for example. But really, accepting any input and using it on *actual file paths* is a read flag; you should probably just store those in a database and use your own file names for the actual files on disk.

Comment: And trying to prevent the input in an HTML widget is pointless, this requires *server side validation* at the very least.

Comment: You may want to check this question as it covers multiple excellent methods for doing this with Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

If using jquery, then below code will allow only alphanumeric values

```
$('#yourInputTag').bind('keyup', function(e) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, ''));
        if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
            var newKey = e.which - 32;
            e.keyCode = newKey;
            e.charCode = newKey;
        }
        $(this).val(($(this).val()));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind a onkeyup function with your input which will fire everytime a key is pressed and replace your input value there.

```
<html>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter value" onkeyup="checkValueWithRegex()" id="myInput">
<script>
function checkValueWithRegex() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  value = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = value;
}
</script>
</html>
```